# Mathematical reason for 2-player turn-based games

Tags: computational-complexity, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I've been reading [Games, Puzzles, and Computation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004A16EUK) which analyzes games through game theory and complexity theory.

The authors introduce something called "Constraint Logic" as a way of modeling games and proving their complexity class. For example, we can make a reduction from NP-Complete problems to a general Constraint Logic form to determine NP-Hardness. I mostly skipped to the proofs on 1- and 2-player games. Like most 2-player games, the 2-player games used are turn-based.

I was wondering if there is some mathematical reason for why most 2-player games are turn-based, instead of simultaneous move. Also, can it be proven that the order of turns does or doesn't affect the fairness of the game?

Comment: The turn order of the game Nim does give an advantage to the first player, but I don t know about other games like Chess. Maybe turn-based games are preferred to prevent ties like in rock-paper-scissors

Comment: A fair number of games are simultaneous move, like many of those in game theory and even a number of recreational games such as Diplomacy or some auction games. I imagine the problem is just that if the choices are in any way complicated, you need detailed conflict resolution rules (as in Diplomacy), which may not be fun for too many people.

Comment: I assume that with "most 2-player games" you mean actual, daily-life parlour games. Simultaneous-move games require that a move cannot be picked off strategically due to it being executed fractionally earlier. Here's [a robot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nxjjztQKtY) beating you at [rock-paper-scissors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors). For that reason, it is a bit difficult to imagine, e.g., a simultaneous-move chess game. Only games that demand the execution of the actions to take place before the revelation of the actions seem suited. Card games can do that much better.

Comment: @Gugg yes, as in board games. If a board game like chess is modified to demand that the players execute their actions before revelation on the board, would the game still be interesting?

Comment: You'd need some modification to the rules, but with that, why not? Also see https://duckduckgo.com/c/Chess_variants and, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung-fu_chess. It seems that any such games might do better on a server rather than on a real board.

Comment: One of the strongest claims made in the book is that Constraint Logic can be adapted to prove the complexity of any n-player game. If anyone has read the book or research on this, can Constraint Logic also prove the complexity of simultaneous-move games? I don't know if the authors had such cases in mind.